# geom_crossbar ignores alpha parameter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add summary statistics to my plot but want them to have some transparency. This does not seem to work with geom_crossbar. Taking the example code [from the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_linerange.html):

```
df <- data.frame(
trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)),
upper = c(1.1, 5.3, 3.3, 4.2),
lower = c(0.8, 4.6, 2.4, 3.6)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(trt, resp, colour = group))
p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, alpha=0.3)
```

works fine, i.e. the errorbars are transparent. However, if I use

```
p + geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, alpha=0.3)
```

instead, the transparency does not work. Am I missing something?

**edit:** the answer from mt1022 works with the example code. However, when I try to add it to my actual plot, the transparency doesn't work anymore plus it changes all the other colors in the plot.

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3458540/plotdata3.RData) is the data and this is my command:

```
ggplot(plotdata3, aes(x=Ncases, y=Intercept.ols, group=col, colour=col)) + geom_point() + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", alpha=0.3, aes(group=1)) +
stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot", geom="crossbar", width=0.08, aes(group=1)) + scale_color_manual(values=rgb(matrix(rep(0,27), ncol=3),alpha = 0.5)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.1)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

When I leave out the scale_color_manual() part the plot looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG18j.jpg) and now I want to make the crossbars transparent, like the straight line is.

Comment: Use `ggplot(plotdata3, aes(x=Ncases, y=Intercept.ols, group=col, colour=col)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", alpha=0.3, aes(group=1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot", geom="crossbar", width=0.08, aes(group=1), color = "#30303030") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.1)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))`.

Comment: ok, thanks, but now you've worked around the problem of supplying an alpha parameter. so if I wanted to change the transparency level, I need to figure out a new color code. Could you maybe say how you've arrived at that value or how to compute such a value from R,G,B and alpha values?

Comment: Just like R,G,B, it's another channel which can have values between 0 and 255. E.g. `adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = .5)` or `rgb(1,0,0, alpha = .5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're going for here but there seem to be a couple of problems. For one thing you are are using color to distinguish among 9 different categories ("col"). Even with ggplot's default palette (hues equally spaced around the color wheel), the colors are barely distinguishable from each other. This problem is made worse by the choice of point size, and by the fact that you put the points underneath the summary graphics (line and crossbar). You might be better off to

1. put the points on top,
2. use point shape 21 (filled circle) and bind fill to the "col", and
3. use a Brewer palette

Below are two examples, the plot generated by @lukeA's solution (which does in fact answer the question), and a plot implementing the suggestions above.

```
ggplot(plotdata3, aes(x=Ncases, y=Intercept.ols, group=col, colour=col)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", alpha=0.3, aes(group=1)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot", geom="crossbar", 
               width=0.08, aes(group=1), color = "#30303030") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.1)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(plotdata3, aes(x=Ncases, y=Intercept.ols)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group=1), fun.y="mean", geom="line", alpha=0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot", geom="crossbar", 
               width=0.08, fill="grey80", color="grey50") + 
  geom_point(aes(group=col, fill=col), size=3, shape=21)  +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.1)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]

The second plot makes it clear that "col" 6 and 9 tend to be significantly below the mean, and "col" 1 and 7 tend to be significantly above the mean.

Answer (score 1):

the `alpha` parameter in `geom_crossbar` controls transparency of filling color;
If you specify a filling color and tune the `alpha`, the transparency of filling color will change but the border color won't change;

```
p + geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, alpha=0.2, fill = 'red')
p + geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, alpha=0.8, fill = 'red')
```

if you want to give transparency to border color, your can use `scale_colour_manual` with transparent color:

```
p + geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2) +
    scale_color_manual(values = rgb(c(1, 0), c(0, 1), 0, alpha = 0.2))
```

there might be other easier solutions.

Comment: ok, this works with the minimal example, but now the scale messes up the colors of the rest of my plot. is there any way to limit the scale to the crossbar geom?

Comment: sorry. I didn't expect this and I can think of a solution to the new porblem. May be you can edit your question and provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

`colour="transparent"` would make the job, and `position=position_dodge(0.1)`
will avoid overlaps.

```
p + geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, colour="transparent", position=position_dodge(0.1))
```